# Inherit multiple model and override method of one of them

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I'm trying to override `create` method from `maintenance.request` to send my template (to notify maintenance team members about new request). To do this I also need to inherit `mail.thread`. And here is my problem.

I have `model.py` like this:

```py
class custom_maintenance_notify(models.Model):
    _name = 'maintenance.request'
    _inherit = ['maintenance.request','mail.thread']

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        record = super(MaintenanceRequest, self).create(vals)

        template_id = self.env.ref('custom_maintenance.new_request_template').id
        if template_id:
            record.message_post_with_template(template_id)
        return record
```

`mail_template.xml` like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <!-- <data noupdate="0"> -->
    <data>
        <record id="new_request_template" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">New maintenance request</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="maintenance.model_maintenance_request"/>
            <field name="subject">New maintenance request - ${object.company_id.name}</field>
            <field name="partner_to">${",".join(map(str, object.maintenance_team_id.member_ids.mapped('partner_id').ids))}</field>
            <field name="body_html" type="xml">
<div>
Test
</div>
            </field>
            <field name="lang">${object.partner_id.lang}</field>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="False"/>
            <field name="user_signature" eval="False"/>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

And `_manifest_` like this:

```py
    'depends': ['base','web','maintenance','mail'],

    'data': [
        # ...
        'data/mail_template.xml',
    ],
```

When I'm trying to create new maintenance record I get this error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/custom_maintenance/models/models.py", line 35, in create
    record = super(MaintenanceRequest, self).create(vals)
NameError: name 'MaintenanceRequest' is not defined
```

So I tried to change `_name` to MaintenanceRequest but with this I can not even upgrade the model and I get this error:

```
ValueError: The _name attribute MaintenanceRequest is not valid.
```

Same result with renaming class as well.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i've already written in the other question:

`super` should be called with the class name, which is `custom_maintenance_notify` in your example, or because you're using Python 3 you can simply use `super()` without parameters.

```py
    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        record = super().create(vals)

        template_id = self.env.ref('custom_maintenance.new_request_template').id
        if template_id:
            record.message_post_with_template(template_id)
        return record
```

And even if you want to override `mail.thread`'s (it's an abstract model or interface in other languages) methods, you don't have to inherit again:

```py
class MaintenanceRequest(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'maintenance.request'

    # override a mail.thread method
    @api.model
    def message_new(self, msg_dict, custom_values=None):
        res = super().message_new(msg_dict, custom_values)
        # do stuff
        return res
```

Last but not least: try to stick to the Odoo Naming Convention. That's what i've done in the example above: the class name is exactly the same as in Odoo's original code.